# Creating assertions in SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, assertion

This is the database:

```
student_worker(name, phone, hourly_wage)
staff_worker(name, office, phone salary)
address(name, street, city)
```

How would you go about creating an SQL assertion that makes sure that every name that appears in the relation address appears in either student_worker or staff_worker, but doesn't necessarily have to be both?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, where are the ids in your table?  Why would you use names to connect them?

Comment: This is all the information that was given to us. I unfortunately don't know how to answer your questions.

Comment: . . Do you specifically mean "assertion" as defined in Postgres or just more generally ensuring that the condition is true.

Comment: I mean using the assertion keyword. I know this keyword isn't identified in most DBMS but this is how we were instructed to do so.

Answer (score 0):

YOu do not. What you do is this this really bad database design.

See, PEOPLE is the one table, not student_worker or staff_worker - those are ROLES that people have at times, but the one table should be entity, human_entity or whatever you name it.

Depending on the database you could have some luck with a trigger, but it would be really really really really a bandaid over a totally broken table design.

AND over reality, because you DO have familities where people have very similar names. You do not account for reality.

Comment: This is actually not a really database being used but rather for educational purposes.